# Having issues saving altered value in a view pre render

Tags: views, 8

I am trying to remove image tags in the view prerender. I've looked through articles and StackExchange and I have set it up correctly. But when I refresh the page containing the view, all the HTML tags are now present as a string.

Here's my code.

```php
function mytheme_views_pre_render(Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == "news" && $view->current_display == 'block_1') {
    foreach ($view->result as $row) {
      $body = $row->_entity->body->value;
      $stripped_img = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+\>/i', '', $body);
      if ($stripped_img != $body) {
        $row->_entity->body->setValue($stripped_img);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the format of body to `full_html` try with:

```
function mytheme_views_pre_render(Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == "news" && $view->current_display == 'block_1') {
    foreach ($view->result as $key => $row) {
      $body = $row->_entity->body->value;
      $stripped_img = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+\>/i', '', $body);
      if ($stripped_img != $body) {
        $row->_entity->body->setValue($stripped_img);
        // Here set the format of body to full_html
        $row->_entity->body->format='full_html';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what it was.

Comment: You are welcome, i'm glad that help!